# python scripts for router

Tags: python, database, paramiko

I am a beginner. I use paramiko to push configuration to devices. I use anaconda on a windows machine. How do I use database and proper formatting to take the output? Please suggest some learning on exception handling.

```
import paramiko
import sys
import subprocess
import time


vm = paramiko.SSHClient()
vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
vm.connect('x.x.x.x', username='your_user_name', password='your_password')
rtrlist = ["a","b"]

for n in rtrlist:
remote_conn_pre=paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(n, port=22, username='your_user_name', password='your_password', look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)


remote_conn.send("conf t\n")
time.sleep(.5)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print (output)

remote_conn.send("flow exporter Netflow-Exporter-Mazu\n")
time.sleep(.5)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print (output)



remote_conn.send("do wr\n")
time.sleep(.5)
output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
print (output)



vm.close()
```

Comment: Can you give code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: See Paramiko's [documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/ssh_exception.html) for more details

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used mongodb, pymongo, paramiko, get_transport().
Was able to pick data from database.
Was able to dry run . Having few hiccups on the exceptions. Anyhow, I am able complete current task.